# Trying to not use watchers in my controllers

Tags: angularjs

So, i'm trying to not use watcher in my controller, but, how could i get a value when it changes?

here is my Controller(MyController) using a listener from my Service:

```
        /**
         * @param Int index
         */
        myService.listener.setDrawAttentionIndex = function (idTask) {
            if (lodash.isNumber(idTask) && !lodash.isNaN(idTask)) {
                if ($scope.task.idFromTask === idTask) {
                    $scope.goal.selectedDrawAttention = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.goal.selectedDrawAttention = false;
                }
            }
        };
```

and here is my Service:

```
        /**
         * @param Int index
         */
        this.setDrawAttention = function (idTask) {
            if (lodash.isNumber(idTask) && !lodash.isNaN(idTask)) {
                drawAttentionIndex = idTask;
                that.listener.setDrawAttentionIndex(idTask);
            }
        };
```

and my possible watcher:

```
        $scope.$watch('myService.getDrawAttention()', function (index) {
            if (lodash.isNumber(index) && !lodash.isNaN(index)) {
                if ($scope.task.idFromTask === index) {
                    $scope.goal.selectedDrawAttention = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.goal.selectedDrawAttention = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

What's better to use? I don't want use watcher in my controller because it's difficult to  test, but, i don't know how i could get the value when it changes... It's a good idea to put a listener from my Service, like i did above? And what happens with my $scope variable inside my service listener?

Comment: Are you able to better explain what you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I don't want to use "watch" inside controllers...

Comment: So don't then. Unless we can understand why you are using a watch in your controller in the first place, how can we recommend alternatives?

Comment: What's better to use? I don't want use watcher in my controller because it's difficult to test, but, i don't know how i could get the value when it changes... It's a good idea to put a listener from my Service, like i did above? And what happens with my $scope variable inside my service listener?

Comment: what you don't understood?